# Showing up-vote/down-vote of question by clicking in reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, voting

In reviewing (for example in `Helps and Improvement`) we can see the current vote of the question or the answer.

I think it can be helpful if reviewrs to be able to click on the vote and it shows the up-vote/down-vote.

Comment: Why is that helpful during reviewing? (If [this still works](http://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep-less-than-1000) you can achieve that for your self)

Comment: @rene When I am reviewing in some reviews like *Low Quality Posts* or *Help and Improvement*, If found the question or answer has some up-votes it tells me that I should take more  attention -at least- on my actions because some users found that as a helpful post ;).

Comment: I rather have reviewers focus on the post and not on voting or rep of users to base their decision on. Maybe you will use this feature in full faith but I can see it being misused as well leading to more wrong reviews.